# De-Cluster SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering

Is there any way to 'de-cluster' an instance of SQL Server 2012 that was installed using the 'New SQL Server Cluster Installation' option? We are having issues with the failover portion of clustering services and since we did not implement the cluster (and really there is no need) we would like to turn this into a stand-alone installation. Removing the Windows Clustering portion just took SQL down with it. All help and insight is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this through the installer. Choose remove node from cluster in the SQL Server installer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191545.aspx

Comment: Would this also remove the 'named' cluster portion? We have the one default instance right now that is handling all traffic using an alias.

Comment: I believe it would leave you with a single-node cluster that bears the name of the cluster. From there, you would evict the node that you just removed from the cluster. Then you could install a separate instance on that piece of hardware.